# retrieved asset is nil ios cordova-plugin-photo-library ionic 1 ios

Tags: ipad, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ios11

i am getting above error while saving image on album on ipad (ios 11) but its working for ios 10 how to resolve this error.
    I have used this plugin for image saving

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-photo-library

              var url1 = result.nativeURL;//'file:///...'; // fil
                var album = 'sk';
                cordova.plugins.photoLibrary.saveImage(url1, album, function (libraryItem) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(libraryItem));

                }, function (err) {
                    alert("errss"+JSON.stringify(err));
                });
how to resolve above error for ios 11
```